# Acessing MapView of class inside button on click listner

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I cant get map view(m) inside my button onclick listner for toggling the views. Could any1 help me.

```
MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mc = getController();
mc.animateTo(p);
mc.setZoom(10);

Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     if (mapView.isSatellite()) 
     {   
        mapView.setSatellite(false);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
     } else 
     {
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(false);
```

Comment: Please, provide some more details. What is the error? No one can help you with this lack of information about your problem.

Comment: I am not getting an instance of map view from my class inside button action. There is not error. Cud u help me with any set or get method to access the map view object inside button on click of my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity/Fragment, create a class member variable for your MapView:

```
private MapView m;
```

in your onCreate() method, assign this variable the view for MapView:

```
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


     m = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);   // the @id setting in your layout of your MapView

    .
    .
    .
    }
```

then you can use m in your button onClick handler